# quirk while hovering menu bar with item count

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

When I go on meta.stackexchange.com and sort by [newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), there is often an item count for the number of **featured** questions.

[image]

Ad then when hovering over the **featured** tab, the hovering action 
produces a slight jump of content, because the red border bottom of the 
hover action is shoving content down by 2px.

[image]

Perhaps this can be seen more clearly in this screenshot, where it is more 
obvious that the border underneath the featured tab has been shoved down
and is not vertically aligned with the red border bottom of the "newest" tab.

[image]

That being said, I am not able to reproduce this bug on any computer and OS, 
but I can say this is happening on my 64-bit Windows 7 machine in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122 m.

Are others ever having this issue?

---

There is one way to fix this.

If I change the CSS for the **`.bounty-indicator-tab`** by adding a **`margin-bottom: -1px`**, the problem goes away.

Comment: Are you sure you have the most up to date css file? Perhaps you could try using `ctrl`+`f5` to see if a cached css file caused this. Otherwise, are you running any extensions?

Comment: Not a CSS caching issue, as I have already cleared the cache previously for other reasons (and just now as well). Extensions running included Angular Batarang, Knockoutjs context debugger, and Google docs, but disabling those extensions changes nothing.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: Just got the Chrome 38.0.2125.122 m update. Still [meta-tag:status-norepro].

Answer (score 2):

No-repro with 64 bit Windows 8 in Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m for me either:

[image]

Or in IE 11, version 11.0.9600.17351:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this using a 64-bit windows 7 machine with chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m and Version 38.0.2125.122 m

[image]